# Flatten Fillable PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, outsystems, flatten-pdf

Thank you in advance for your assistance. I need to flatten a fillable pdf using very basic javascript. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? My other 2 options are if anyone has a solution in Outsystems to flatten a fillable pdf, or a c# simple solution to flatten a pdf.

Comment: You need some npm library to do the work for you? Are you working in node?

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to write an extension module that uses some pdf libary that can flatten the pdf.